# batch file: Save exported text file as encoding utf-8

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I created a batch file to export some data from a software that I use.  It exports the data and it saves the data in text format.  exactly what I need it to do but the problem is that the encoding for the export text file is saved as ANSI.  I need it to be saved a utf-8_bin.  The reason for this is because I need it be imported into MySQL.  The schema for MySQL is utf-8_bin.

Here is the batch file:

```
START /WAIT ksexport.exe /NOP /NODISPLAY Type=SA File=xprt\Sle\SInv.txt File2=xprt\Sle\SInvDtl.txt Tab=on Start=01/01/01 End=01/30/17
```

Comment: [chcp 65001](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) _could_ help.

Comment: from your question is not clear is the ksexport your software or some 3rdparty. In case you write there are ways to get what you need. In case it's some known you may want to add some tags to attract experts on the software.

Comment: as for the 1st option, you might be interested to read [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20130101094000/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2008/03/18/8306597.aspx). Or you can just use binary IO

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try in your batch script something like:

```
@ECHO OFF
:: Make sure that your batch file is in "UTF-8 without BOM" encoding
:: Notepad++ have the ability to change the file encoding

:: Then, change the codepage in your script:
CHCP 65001

:: And now, you can export your data without problems
START /WAIT ksexport.exe /NOP /NODISPLAY Type=SA File=xprt\Sle\SInv.txt File2=xprt\Sle\SInvDtl.txt Tab=on Start=01/01/01 End=01/30/17

::EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **CMD.EXE /U**, i.e.:

```
start /wait %COMSPEC% /U /C ksexport.exe ........
```

The **/U** makes **CMD.EXE** output Unicode text.  I'm not sure if this will affect the output of **KSEXPORT.EXE** though.

Alternatively, use PowerShell ;-)

Comment: Read `cmd /?` help: `/U` Causes the output of **internal commands** to a pipe or file to be Unicode.

Comment: "start /wait %COMSPEC% /U /C ksexport.exe ........" didn't work.  Do you think ANSI is just as good as utf-8.  the reason i need utf-8_bin is because my schema in mysql is utf-8.  should i just change the unicode to ANSI in mysql or do you think i may issues in the future with mysql.